# Handle workspace/monorepo with different deployments

Tags: solidity, contract-development, subgraph

I am using yarn workspaces in which I have 2 projects.

```
My-project
   contracts
   subgraph
```

Some devs work on contracts, others on subgraph. The flow of the release is the following:

- PRs are created on feature branches and merged to develop.
- The process of PRs continue and they all get merged to develop. At some point, we decide whether release is due, so develop is merged into main branch.
- From main, we create a release candidate and deploy scripts on productions are run.

The problem that happens for us is that `subgraph` needs to be released much quicker(every day) because sometimes of new features or bug fixes, whereas `contracts` release happens very rarely(every month) even though contracts code changes every day(it's just release must happen every month), because as you know, we don't want un-audited contracts code on main branch.

**The problem:** When the team works on feature branches and merges things to develop, it happens that develop branch ends up containing `contracts` and `subgraph`'s changed files. If we want to release `subgraph` every day, we got no choice but to merge develop into main in which case changed `contract`’s code also moves into main which is not ideal.

One thing that I looked into is using `git checkout /paths` which only moves the specific folder from one branch to another - i.e I could use this to only move `subgraph` folder from develop to main, but I am not sure if this is the right and best practice.